# Three.js how to show SVG animating image with WebGLRenderer?

Tags: svg, three.js

what is the best way to show svg animating image in a WebGLRenderer without using SVGRenderer?

the code attached shows the image but it dose not animate.

```
var spriteMap = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( assetPath1 + ".svg",
            function(texture)
            {
                texture.needsUpdate = true;
                var spriteMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( {map: texture} );
                var sprite = new THREE.Sprite( spriteMaterial );
                loadingScene.add( sprite );
            }
```